# How To Change The Button Text "Add to cart" in Wooccomerce With The Divi Theme

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, divi

I am trying to change the **Add To Cart** text on the product page button to **Buy Now**
I've tried using the function that's being posted everywhere to solve the issue but somehow that doesn't seem to do the trick, also using a WordPress plugin is not changing the text.

So far I've found the following **function**

```
// To change add to cart text on single product page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' ); 
function woocommerce_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {
    return __( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' ); 
}

// To change add to cart text on product archives(Collection) page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text' );  
function woocommerce_custom_product_add_to_cart_text() {
    return __( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

Adding that to my **Code Inserter** creates an error and breaks the website.

I think that Divi is overruling the function from somewhere. Any tips or ideas?

Comment: Probably related to your "code inserter", I am guessing that likely doesn't see to it that this executes at a sensible time. Stuff like this should rather get placed into the functions.php, than be executed arbitrarily by one of those terrible "execute PHP code dynamically" plugins(?).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply CBroe. I did indeed try the fuinctions.php. That took the website offline as well.

Comment: _"breaks the website"_ and _"took the website offline as well"_ are far from an _actual_ problem analysis. You'll need to start by investigating this a bit more thoroughly, and figure out what the reasons for any such errors really are.